# The flutter app doesn't run with java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitVarDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1164)
... ... ...
... ... ...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

When I run my flutter app on visual code and LD Player, I face the above error.
Here is my java version

```
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-27990 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-27990 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Please help me Fluter experts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountere that problem.
Try downgrade jdk version.
Hope it helps!